# Keep return of service Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, service, scope

In my component I call a service which returns a list of objects

```
  public controls: Control[];

constructor(
    private readonly controlService: ControlService,
  ) { }


public onSubmit(): void {
this.controleService.getControls(
        this.idPerson,
        this.getMomentDate(dControlDate),
        this.getMomentDate(fControleDate),
      ).subscribe(c=> {
        this.controls = c.response.controls;   //OK, FILLED LIST
      });
}

exportToCSV() {
    console.log(this.controls);  // UNDEFINED LIST....
  }
```

I would like to have another method "exportToCSV" which exports this controls list when I click on a button. The problem is that my controls variable is undefined when I am outside the subscribe.

How can I keep my controls list (this.controls) to use in my exportToCSV method?

Thank for your help

Comment: Do you always call `onSubmit()` before `exportToCSV()`?

Comment: After this line is executed `this.controls = c.response.controls` this.controls value will change. and you can find this change anywhere inside the class. just make sure you are not calling `exportToCSV()` before the subscription changes this `controls` value

Comment: yes, onSubmit is always called before (it's a search)

exportToCSV () will be called when there is a click on another button.
the value this.controls is lost at this time because we are no longer in the subscribe. so my question is
 : how can I keep the return of my service?

Comment: @Nitneuq: `this.controls` will not be lost. It is assigned asynchronously. So `exportToCSV()` function has no idea if the `this.controls` contains the value. It may happen that the `exportToCSV()` function is called as soon as the `onSubmit()` is triggered. In that case, the `this.controls` is not assigned the values yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `exportToCSV` method like this: `exportToCSV(controls: Control[])`. then just after `this.controls = c.response.control`, call `this.exportToCSV(this.controls)`, then call `exportToCSV` when click.

You can't call exportToCSV() and try to check the value of this.controls before call onSubmit() method because the controls attribute change value at the end of onSubmit() execution.

Comment: yes but the problem is that the exportToCSV() method will be called before I even click on "Export". no ?

Comment: Yes. But you should consider that there is some time onSumbit will take for execution. If exportToCSV is called before the end of execution of onSubmit, the value of controls will still be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is instantiated for each component that uses it, then you have no access to the property.

By making it a singleton, you share the same instance of the service everywhere -- meaning that you can access values shared in it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // This flags the service as a singleton
})
export class YourService {
  public controls: Control[];

  constructor( private readonly controlService: ControlService) { }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.controleService.getControls(
      this.idPerson,
      this.getMomentDate(dControlDate),
      this.getMomentDate(fControleDate),
      ).subscribe(c=> {
        this.controls = c.response.controls;
      });
  }

  public exportToCSV() {
    console.log(this.controls);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `this.controls` is assigned value asynchronously. Any statements that depend on it should also be asynchronous to ensure the value is available when accessed. One way would be to make `this.controls` an RxJS Observable. Try the following

```js
import { iif, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class SomeComponent {
  public controls = new BehaviorSubject<Control[]>(null);

  constructor(
    private readonly controlService: ControlService,
  ) { }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.controleService.getControls(
      this.idPerson,
      this.getMomentDate(dControlDate),
      this.getMomentDate(fControleDate),
    ).subscribe(c => {
      this.controls.next(c.response.controls);        // <-- push value to observable
    });
  }

  exportToCSV() {
    iif(() => 
      this.controls.value.length > 0,
      this.controls.pipe(take(1)),    // <-- values assigned - use default value and complete
      this.controls.pipe(take(2)),    // <-- values not assigned - ignore default value (empty array)
    ).subscribe(
      controls => { 
        if (controls.length > 0) {
          console.log(this.controls);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `exportToCSV` method in your subscribe and pass control data as argument.

```
public controls: Control[];

constructor(
  private readonly controlService: ControlService,
) { }


public onSubmit(): void {
this.controleService.getControls(
    this.idPerson,
    this.getMomentDate(dControlDate),
    this.getMomentDate(fControleDate),
  ).subscribe(c=> {
    this.controls = c.response.controls;   //OK, FILLED LIST
    this.exportToCSV(this.controls);
  });
}

exportToCSV(controls) {
  console.log(controls);  // UNDEFINED LIST....
}
```

In this scenario `exportToCSV` will execute once you will get data in `this.controls` and in `exportToCSV` console won't print undefined.

Let me know if you have any doubt.